# Passing Bundle Names to External Mail Clients

Tags: gmail, google-inbox

Is there any way to access the bundle in an email is in? I like Inbox but need to use a desktop client so I can unify all of my accounts into one place. I'd like to make rules, either at the Inbox level or in my client, Airmail, to put items into folders that match their bundle names.

Comment: Have you tried or researched anything? If so, please edit your question.

Comment: I examined the mail file delivered from Inbox to 3rd party mail clients via IMAP/POP and I saw no signs that they were passing the bundle name.